# Where would a British Captain and his wife live in Boston in 1773?

Tags: boston

I am writing an historical novel and the two main characters, a colonist who marries a British Captain, move to Boston when he is transferred there. Where would they live. His job was to oversee the wharf area of Boston.

Comment: What sort of Captain? Army or navy?

Comment: Almost certainly very close to the place he'd be working. Not on the wharf itself, but in a pretty decent house nearby.

Comment: He's a British Army Captain, but has guard duty at the wharf, overseeing goods brought into the colony through the port. I'm hoping the find some names of streets where he might have found a house to live in. A place in the northern part so they can hear the fighting at Breed's Hill later.